# How can I troubleshoot vmnet routing on my MacOShost and Linux guest with VMWare Fusion?

Tags: networking, nat, vmware-fusion

I am running a Linux guest VM on my Mac (MacOS 10.7.5) with VMWare Fusion 5.0.3.

The Linux guest VM expects to have a specific IP address - 192.168.56.10

The VMs network is set to be NAT ("Share with my Mac")

I have set up my vmnet8 NAT and DHCP such that DHCP allocates IP address in the 192.168.56.255 range, and that the VM gets allocated the specific IP address.

The VM starts up fine. It is getting the correct IP address. From within the VM, I can see the outside world.

However, I cannot connect to my VM from my host.

Sshd and Apache are both running and listening on the appropriate network adapter.

The same VM works on a colleague's machine with the same settings.

I suspect it is a routing issue from my Mac host to the guest VM, but I do not know what to look for to determine if this is the case. I am reasonably computer-savvy, but not a networking expert.

Comment: +1  Well thought out, with good detail.  I wish I knew how to help with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a networking expert either, but the way I solved a similar problem was to edit the VMware Fusion settings for the VM that I want to connect to.  I enable the Network Adapter and select Ethernet under Bridged Networking.  I then reboot the VM.

If you're not locked in to that 192.168.56.10 address, then maybe something like this would help.

Comment: The VM, unfortunately, needs to have the 192.168.56.10 IP address. I cannot connect to the guest VM via ssh or http from the host. The guest works fine on its own. I suspect the issue is with routing within MacOS rather than with the VM